Boto3 dynamoDB query date range
In my dynamoDB table, I have a colum called last_updated. An example of the format of this field is 2023-05-26 14:29:50.
I would like to query the table, for all records between a specific date range. For example, the last three days.  For that, i have the following:
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('my_table')

now = datetime.now() # 2024-05-07 16:35:48.793364
three_days_ago = now - timedelta(days=3)  # 2024-05-04 16:35:48.793364

filter = Key('last_updated').between(three_days_ago, now); # <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Between object at 0x000002ED71D3F560>

response = table.scan( FilterExpression=filter )
print(response)

Im getting the following error. My guess is its something to do with the data format perhaps?
TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'datetime.datetime'>" for value "2024-05-04 16:35:48.793364"

Any idea's what the issue is here, and how I would go about fixing it?
Thankyou.

Did you try converting the timestamp to str and then query?
